# Hashtag character not displaying correctly

Tags: python, pyautogui

The following fails to print a hashtag?

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.typewrite('#');
```

It prints '~'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sean Kennedy said, it's a keyboard layout issue. They're still working on support for non-US-English keyboard layouts.

https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/137

Luckily you have an English keyboard layout, so you'll have far fewer issues and you should be able to patch them. You can redefine whether certain keys need shift or not by editing `_pyautogui_win.py`:

```
def _keyDown(key):
   if key not in keyboardMapping or keyboardMapping[key] is None: return
   needsShift = pyautogui.isShiftCharacter(key)
   # insert this code, exactly here:
   if key == '#': needsShift = False
   if key == '+': needsShift = False
   if key == '<': needsShift = False
   #print(key,needsShift) #####debug
   # continue
```

Taken from:
https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/46#issuecomment-132640299

<s>I haven't looked at the code myself, but you might find that you're better or worse making the edit inside `isShiftCharacter`.</s>

I should have kept reading. isShiftCharacter might become a rabbit hole:

> By the way: Deleting #,+,< in the following function, did NOT work
>   (util.py in .\pyautogui):
>
> def isShiftCharacter(character):    return character.isupper() or
>   character in '~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?'
>
> Maybe .isupper() regards these characters as upper? I didn't check
>   further

Comment: Most excellent! Linux, so had to edit '_pyautogui_x11.py'. But now working.

Answer (score 1):

Pyautogui is keyboard layout dependent.

You could try switching your keyboard layout to the US keyboard layout (which is what Pyautogui is based on). For example, the French Canadian keyboard layout has a `#` where the `~` key normally is, which could explain why you're experiencing this behavior.

Comment: I need to be able to do it without having to change my keyboard layout from UK to US every time.

Comment: It's puzzling that using pyautogui.hotkey('shift','#'); still outputs ~.Is it possible to output unicode? How?

Comment: What's going on with the following?

>>> pyautogui.keyDown('#');
~>>> ~#####################
KeyboardInterrupt

Running again I get:
>>> pyautogui.keyDown('#');
>>> #####################
KeyboardInterrupt

No ~ this time.

If I then run typewrite('#') it prints nothing, but the second time it prints ~

>>> pyautogui.typewrite('#');
>>> pyautogui.typewrite('#');
~>>> ~

Comment: Running 'pyautogui.typewrite('Hello world! #'); print('#');' prints 'Hello world! ~#'

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be an alternative if `pyautogui` doesn't work for `#`,etc

```
import keyboard
keyboard.write('#')
```